# Local boundedness on a topological space understanding

Tags: general-topology

I know that a real or complex valued function f defined on some topological space X called locally bounded if for any $x_0 \in X$ there exists a neighbourhood A of $x_0$ such that $f(A)$ is a bounded set, that is , for some number $M>0$, $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all x in a.

I have an example of a locally bounded function.

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=2x+3$.

I do not understand the argument which says this is locally bounded.

It is locally bounded because for each a, $|f(x)| \leq M$ in the neighbourhood $(a-1,a+1)$, where $M=2|a|+3$.

Why does $M=2|a|+3$? And when M is as mentioned,  why is $|f(x)| \leq M$?

What is the neighbourhood $(a-1,a+1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(x)|=|2x+3|\leq 2|x|+3$. When $x\in(a-1,a+1)$, then you get $2|x|+3\leq 2|a|+3$.

To give more details: Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Without loss of generality, we may choose the neighbourhood $A$ of $a$ to be the interval $(a-1,a+1)$. Then, when $x\in (a-1,a+1)$, we have $|f(x)|\leq 2|a|+3$ by the above argument. Thus, for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$, if you set your $M=2|a|+3$, you would obtain local boundedness. 
Try to think how you can make this argument work for an arbitrary $A$ (or in other words - why it is indeed without loss of generality that we chose $A=(a-1,a+1)$.

Comment: What possible values could x take though? Because surely a could be anything?

Comment: Please see the edits above. Also, even before them, I wrote: $x\in (a-1,a+1)$ - in other words - $x$ can take any value between $a-1$ and $a+1$. 
Try to draw a picture to see why the argument follows through.

Comment: So is x always between 0 and 1?

Comment: $a-1< x <a+1$ - as you vary your $a$, you vary the possible values for $x$. Your $a$ in the second part of your question is your $x_0$ in the definition of boundedness you gave.